# Why isn't this go HTTP server spawning a goroutine per request in Chrome 47?

Tags: go, concurrency, httpserver

*Previously titled: **How to spawn goroutine per HTTP request?***

The code below is a simple HTTP server that echos the path back to the requester. I used it to test if the `ListenAndServe` method of the `net/http` package by default fires a goroutine to handle each request; which I discovered it doesn't. If I make three requests at the same time, the first takes 10 seconds to return, the second 20 (10 seconds after the first returns), and the third 30 seconds.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "time"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  time.Sleep(10000 * time.Millisecond)
  fmt.Fprint(w, r.URL.Path)
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Basically what I want is the main goroutine to listen for an HTTP connection, then pass the reading of the request and the response to a handler spawned in another goroutine.

Could someone point me in the right direction for accomplishing this? Preferably using the `net/http` package in go.

**UPDATE 12/21/15 08:46 AM MST**

I conducted the same exact test you did using my web browser (chrome 47), five requests at the root of localhost:8080, and the results were roughly:

```
1st: 10 seconds
2nd: 20 seconds
3rd: 30 seconds
4th: 36 seconds     
5th: 38 seconds
```

So, hopefully, the folks who would otherwise down-vote my question would understand my confusion and why I made the assumption I did. I have no idea why I got the results I did on the 4th and 5th request.

I ran the same test using curl and had the same results as @tomasz.

I'm using `go1.2.1`.

**UPDATE 12/21/15 02:08 PM MST**

Per @tomasz's suggestion below, I retitled this question from "How to spawn goroutine per HTTP request" to "Why isn't this go HTTP server spawning a goroutine per request in Chrome 47?"

Comment: I do understand your confusion. You've seen some behaviour and made a false conclusion and then based on this you asked your question. It was well worded, so I was able to answer. I guess if you skipped the conclusion about routines and just asked why this is not working as expected, you would have more luck and collect some upvotes. One way or another I hope your problem is now solved. Per my update, you can also see this working correctly in Chrome by opening multiple tabs with a different URL each.

Comment: You may have realized by now, but the first thing to do when troubleshooting basic HTTP is to get the browser out of the equation -- in only introduces browser-specific behavior. Also, update your Go install, learning with such an old version is only going to hamper you with mismatched documentation and possibly missing features.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

All is good, your handler is run in a separate routine for each request. Take a look at the source code of [`http.Server.Serve`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1883) method. The last line in accepting loop says:

```
go c.serve()
```

The problem is probably with your testing. If you check the behaviour through the multiple tabs in browser the requests for matching URLs are probably queued instead of running them simultaneously (i.e. your client is not using "routines", not the server).

Try two different browsers or just use command line and, say, `curl` to test requests in parallel. For example (with some help from bash):

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do time curl localhost:8080 &; done
# after ignoring some mess...
curl localhost:8080  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.013 total
curl localhost:8080  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.014 total
curl localhost:8080  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.012 total
curl localhost:8080  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.019 total
```

You server works like a charm.

**Update**

I can confirm this behaviour on Chrome 47, but also noticed you can open multiple tabs with, say, `http://localhost:8080/test1`, `http://localhost:8080/test2` etc. and you will get expected results. That indicates there's indeed some queuing mechanism in Chrome for matching URLs.

Comment: Confirming this on Chromium 69. On Firefox 62 it works as intended though: I refresh all tabs simultaneously and the queries finish at the same time.